# Window-slide through an image

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

**Objective:** Slide a 2D 'window' through a 2D image (grayscale). For each pixel of the image, copy all the pixels inside the window (pattern) and move to the next pixel.

**Problem:** Very Slow. I want to speed this up.

Except by using Cython (ewwww).

I use this code in a server with 48 cores, so parallel processing is an option.
Therefore, Im confused on how to approach a multi-thread solution with numpy.

**Description:** I have a method called extract. This method receives a grayscale image, the position i and j which refers to the x-axis and y-axis of the image where the window is centered at. For each position, i and j, I copy what the window sees to another array.

`img` is a 2d NumPy array.

`pat` could be removed and I could return the pattern. Doesn't matter.

`i` and `j` are integers.

```
def extract(self, img, i, j, pat):
        pattern = pat
        win = self.window
        hh = win.shape[0]
        ww = win.shape[1]
        hh2 = hh / 2
        ww2 = ww / 2
        k = 0

        for l in range(-hh2, hh2 + 1):
            for m in range(-ww2, ww2 + 1):
                    try:
                        pattern[k] = img[i + l, j + m]
                    except:
                        pattern[k] = 0
                    k += 1
```

Comment: What is the exception that `except` is meant to catch? Is it just so you don't have to test boundary conditions, or something more?

Comment: @abarnet Yes, So I dont have to test boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is to vectorize those loops. Without a complete example, it's hard to test anything, so I'll just give a sketch.

We want to turn this:

```
for m in range(-ww2, ww2 + 1):
        try:
            pattern[k] = img[i + l, j + m]
        except:
            pattern[k] = 0
        k += 1
```

… into a single assignment over slices of `pattern` and `img`, instead of a loop over assignment to indices of `pattern` and `img`.

---

First, let's forget about the boundary stuff to make it simpler. How can we get those `i + l`, `j + m`, and `k` all vectorized together?

- `m` is the index from your range, and `j` is constant, so `j + m` ranges over `j-ww2:j+ww2+1`.
- `k` is the index from your range minus the start value of the range. So it goes from `ww2:2*ww2+1`.
- `i` and `l` are both constant in the inner loop, so we don't need to change anything there at all.

So:

```
pattern[ww2:2*ww2+1] = img[i + l, j-ww2:j+ww2+1]
```

---

Now, what about the boundary problem? That's always a bit of a pain—and here's where I can be the least help because I don't know exactly how these values relate to each other or which boundaries you're worried about—but you probably need something like this:

```
lok, hik = ww2, 2*ww2+1
lojm, hijm = max(0, j-ww2), min(j+ww2+1, width)
pattern[lok:hik] = img[i+l, lojm:hijm]
```

If there needs to be a 0 on one edge or the other, the quick&dirty answer is to just stick that in manually, like:

```
if hijm == width:
    pattern[hik] = 0
```

---

Once you get this working, it should hopefully speed up your inner loop by around an order of magnitude.

If the inner loop is decent-sized (that is, `ww2` isn't a tiny number), you may just be done. If it's tiny, you probably need to do a similar transformation to the outer loop, but it's no harder than the one we just did.